Truffle Test Executed with 0 passing
I am new to blockchain and trying to learn blockchain using Etherium environment with ReactJS. For learning purpose, I am following below link:
https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/blockchain-tutorial
Everthing is working as per expplained in above link till the test case executing step. When I run truffle test then codes compiled successfully but with 0 passing.
Below is my test case code written in reactJS:
const SocialNetwork = artifacts.require('./socialNetwork.sol')

require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised')).should()

contract('SocialNetwork', (accounts) => {
 let socialNetwork

 before(async () => {
   socialNetwork = await SocialNetwork.deployed()
 })

 describe('deployment', async () => {
   it('has a name', async () => {
     const name = await socialNetwork.name()
     assert.equal(name, 'Dapp Social Network')
   })
 })
})  

Below is the output after running truffle test:
truffle test
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\src\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\SocialNetwork.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\test--26480-U15AuvrMpfHd
> Compiled successfully using:
  - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang


0 passing (1ms)  

I am not able to understand why my test case is not executing. What the issue is and what is causing this. Can someone please help to resolve this issue?
